# FourierTransform doesn't work properly

Tags: fourier-analysis

Here is my code

```
FourierTransform[A*B*(Sin[\[Pi] *B* x]/(\[Pi] *B *x)) cos[2* \[Pi]* x  *C], x, f, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

but it doesn't work in mathematica , but in wolfram alpha it works fine.
[image]
[image]
what is my mistake?

Comment: Check, you don't have uppercase in any case, have you?

Comment: do not use `C,A,B`, use lower case. And try with `Cos` and not `cos`. Mathematica is case sensitive. But Wolfram Alpha might not be. And no need to put `*` in Wolfram Mathematica. Use SPACE instead of `*`, easier to read also. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rFQ7z.png)

Comment: Thanks Nasser and Louis for your help and good tips

Comment: would it possible to tell me why I get this error for specific value of a,b,c?
PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.   for   FourierTransform[((
   Cos[2 (10^9) \[Pi] x] Sin[3 \[Pi] x])/(\[Pi] x))^5, x, f, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

Answer (score 1):

As matter of fact I didn't know that mathematica is case-sensitive. this code should work fine

```
FourierTransform[(a Cos[2 c \[Pi] x] Sin[b \[Pi] x])/(\[Pi] x), x, f, 
FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

Thanks Nasser & Louis for your help